# Как получить список всех запускаемых файлов из Start Menu при старте системы

Tags: c#

подскажите как достать программно список всех запускаемых файлов из Start Menu при старте системы, где смотреть подскажите. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Конкрентно файлов в папке пользователя? Просто этих мест откуда запускается при старте очень много.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вам нужен список autorun, можете его достать из `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

Например, так:

```
using (var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run"))
{
    var valueNames = key.GetValueNames();

    Dictionary<string, string> apps = valueNames.Where(valueName => key.GetValueKind(valueName) == RegistryValueKind.String).ToDictionary(valueName => valueName, valueName => key.GetValue(valueName).ToString());
}
```